# Can't import JSON string to MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, ajax

I'm trying to build a leaderboard web app, with data from 15 countries.

The data needs to be uploaded as an .xls file and imported to a MySQL database.

I have build the upload part, which gives me a valid JSON string.

The string is then posted via ajax, to this script as "output":

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['output'])) {

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname) or die('Error in Connecting: ' . mysqli_error($con));

$st = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO tbl_ttl(country, leads, followup, followuppercent) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($st, 'ssss', $country, $leads, $followup, $followuppercent);

$jsondata = $_POST['output'];

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $country = $row['country'];
    $leads = $row['leads'];
    $followup = $row['followup'];
    $followuppercent = $row['followuppercent'];

    mysqli_stmt_execute($st);
}

echo "Success!";

mysqli_close($con);
```

And this is where im stuck. I do get the "Success!" alert and no errors.

I need to import the records in the string as seperate rows.

And one more thing...

The leaderboard needs to be updated once a month. So is it possible to update the existing rows with new values every time they are uploaded?

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/